# Типы ссылок, полный и не полный адрес

Tags: html, ссылки

Есть ли различия между ссылками

```
<a href="http://site.com/article-page">Статья</a>
или
<a href="/article-page">Статья</a>
```

Т.е как лучше указывать ? ибо я узываю полный путь во всех ссылках, вместо как я понимаю внутреннего ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для посетителей вашего сайта разницы нет. Разница возникает в следующих случаях:

1. Вы решаете изменить домен сайта.
2. Вы решаете изменить протокол с HTTP на HTTPS.

В этом случае вам нужно будет обновить все ссылки на сайте. Если у вас статические страницы или контент со статическими абсолютными ссылками, то возникает проблема: вам нужно будет обновить все ссылки на всём сайте. Это чревато ошибками, например, если пропустить какую-нибудь ссылку, то навигация сломается, и посетитель не найдёт нужную страницу.

Если вы генерируете ссылки программно, например, у вас есть константа "домен сайта" и вы каждый раз её выводите, а не просто копируете полный адрес, то опять-таки проблем нет — вам достаточно изменить одну ссылку. Кроме прочего, такой подход позволяет размещать сайт в подпапке (ссылки вида `/page` будут вест в корень).

Использование же разных видов относительных путей (`/page`, `page`, `//domain/page`) — это метод, который работает при смене домена и протокола независимо от используемой технологии, поэтому обычно ему отдаётся предпочтение.

Comment: Cпасибо большое, я как то об этом не подумал. Возьму на заметку.

Answer (score 2):

Если это ссылка на одну из страниц сайта, над которым Вы работаете, то лучше второй вариант.

Первый вариант - абсолютная, второй - относительная.
Если указать абсолютный путь, а сайт, например, переедет на другой домен, то ссылка уже будет неактивна. А если указать просто href="/article-page", то все будет работать

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю с точки зрения оптимизации для поисковиков, 1-й вариант как полноценная ссылка будет лучше передавать ссылочное, в остальном Squidward прав, поэтому резюмируя я бы занёс в переменную хост сайта с протоколом ("http://site.ru") и ссылки генерировал бы с учётом этой переменной, если конечно позволит движок сайта).

Comment: Такое реализовать можно, но под удар можно поставить весь движек. Так что думаю мы изначально определимся с протоколом, а потом заменим все ссылки, много ума для этого не нужно, проверить их на валидность тоже.

Answer (score 0):

все зависит от того где находится ваша статья и сам ваш хтмл файл, если у вас сама статья с чужого источника тогда нужно написать полный адресс(http://site.com/article-page) , если же она находится у вас(например в той же папке где хтмл файл) то можно просто название файла написать,(или же если не в той же папке то пишите адресс статьи ссылаясь на положение Хтмл файла в системе)